# Tracking down the caller of a method [called through an invocation]

Tags: java, dependency-injection, webwork, opensymphony

How would go about tracing down a method invocation from `webwork.util.InjectionUtils` in OpenSymphony Webworks? (I realize that this is an outdated project, but I'm still required to use it)

I'm getting an method that is throwing an exception and I'm not sure how to catch the exception or to prevent it from bailing because of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution to this was to investigate potential invoking points, and to track down the component that was doing the invoking.

Comment: how did you do that? could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't go into detail at the time, but the approach was a shotgun approach to find the exact invoker. Its not the quickest way, but it certainly worked.